# Let an interface inherit from canvas WPF VB.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, class, interface

My interface is defined with a few methods and properties

```
Public Interface ITouchInterface
   'Inherits System.Windows.Controls.Canvas ' This is the problem

   'Methods and Properties

End Interface
```

I understand the problem I have,  the interface can only inherit from another interface and since `System.Windows.Controls.Canvas` is not an interface I cannot inherit from it.

My class which implements the interface rely on the properties of the canvas to function.

Currently my implementation for the interface looks as follows:

```
Public Class TouchClass
    Inherits Canvas
    Implements ITouchInterface

    'Implementation
End Class
```

Basically for this to work with the rest of my application I need the interface to specify the inheritance from canvas. The rest of the application expect an object of type `ITouchInterface`,  but with my current implementation the application is not aware of the canvas properties until a class is instantiated.

For example I declare a list of `ITouchInterface`. It is then populated with classes that implement the interface.  Now I need to loop through this list and get the width of every item, but the width is a property of the canvas and its not accessible at the moment.

Does an interface for canvas exist that I'm not aware of or is there any alternate solutions?

Comment: Do you **need** every `ITouchInterface` to be a `Canvas`, or do you actually need to be able to obtain a `Width` from each one? (Think carefully before answering)

Comment: I need every interface to be a canvas, width is just one of the many properties I need to use.  Also I need the methods of canvas to be able to display it in a window.

Comment: You could add a property to the interface that returns a `Canvas` object. Of course, an implementor could lie and return something other than itself, but if you really do need full access to the `Canvas`, then this is probably the simplest way to make things work.

Comment: Why not use a base class instead of an interface? To me it sounds like that is what you want.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, I only need to make minor adjustments to my implementation to make it work.

Comment: @DjSol The reason for that is because I actually need different assemblies to use implement the classes. I need the interface as a common interface over different assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

you can add an abstract class between which takes the role of your interface. Of course this will result in some more coupling...

this results in exactly what you want: you can have several different implementations of a class which implements ITouchInterface and inherits from canvas

```
Public Interface ITouchInterface

End Interface

Public MustInherit Class TouchCanvasBase
    Inherits Canvas
    Implements ITouchInterface

End Class

Public Class TouchCanvas
    Inherits TouchCanvasBase

    'specific implementation

End Class
```

Comment: Is the interface strictly speaking still required in this case or can I use only the abstract class to describe a general touch class?  I've worked myself into a corner on this one, the has-a relationship won't work in my solution.

Comment: the interface is not absolutely needed. you can define the methods which have to be implemented abstract in the abstract base class

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance still means **is a**, so you are saying your ITouchInterface *is a* Canvas. That sounds wrong.

As said in the comments look at composition instead, which means **has a**. So your touch interface *has a* Canvas. That sounds better already, but still seems not entirely right. Rethink your design and see what the clients of ITouchInterface really need. Do they need the entire Canvas, or just some methods to draw on it, which you could easily put in another interface?